# How to add javascript to static block?

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, javascript, static-block

I have a javascript that I need to add to a static block. Could anyone explain it step by step?

Comment: You can simply use `<script>alert('hello');</script>` in your static block

Comment: I need to add this code - <script type='text/javascript' src='https://widgets.ziftsolutions.com/dell.ziftsolutions.com/js/ff8081815c1976d4015c39a9a83469f1'  charset='utf-8'></script>

Answer (score 2):

Login to the admin and navigate to `content > blocks`, find the block you want to edit and click on `select > edit`.

Click on the `hide/show editor` button to hide the editor (make sure there are no icons above the text box).

Paste in your Javascript and save the static block. If you see a message about cache then click on it and clear the cache.

**Internal JS:**

```
<script>JS Goes Here</script>
```

**External JS:**

```
<script src="path-here.js"></script>
```

**Call a template that contains your JS:**

```
{{block type="core/template" block_id="example.id" template="your/template/path.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your ans. But am really a newbie and i do not know anything about codes. This is the code I need to add in a static block.
 Now can you tell me where to include this code?                                          <script type='text/javascript' src='https://widgets.ziftsolutions.com/dell.ziftsolutions.com/js/ff8081815c1976d4015c39a9a83469f1'  charset='utf-8'></script>

Comment: I have updated my answer with more instructions, you need to find the static block in the admin, paste your code in, then save it and maybe need to clear the cache.

Answer (score 2):

Login to admin panel Click on CMS > Static Blocks.

Create New Block suppose Identifier = block_test

Add Content :

```
Click <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="checkFunction()">here</a> to check Javascript
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
    function checkFunction(){
        alert('test Completed');
    }
// ]]></script>
```

For testing Create CMS page and call CMS block from CMS page

suppose URL Key = test

Add Content :

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="block_test"}}
```

Go to front end /test and click on "here" link, alert message will popup.

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a phtml file in : `app/design/frontend/{yourPackage}/{yourTheme}/template/cms/customcms.phtml` then put your code in this file.(the code that you want to display in a static block, not the external Js URL)

2) Go to admin cms>static block>your static block>content>hide editor>past this code:

`{{block type="core/template name="custom.cms" template="cms/customcms.phtml"}}`

3) add this code in `app/design/frontend/{yourPackage}/{yourTheme}/layout/local.xml`

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
   <default translate="label" module="page">
       ...
       <reference name="head">
          <action method="addLinkRel"><rel>text/javascript</rel><href> https://YOUR URL TO THE EXTERNAL JS ... .js</href></action>
       </reference>
   </default>
</layout>
```